# Comment form on Custom Post type Single page is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type single page template like (`single-portfolio.php`). Inside the template I am using this code

```
 comments_template();
```

For showing comment box. It's not working for Custom post type (CPT)

But the same code working for `single.php`, nicely.

Comment: Seems like comments are disabled by default on custom post types by default. Have a look at this post with regards to solutions: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/38405/102721

Comment: Comments are enabled. I have checked and checked everywhere check marks.